# Why is Kellogg automatically hostile to me?

Tags: fallout-4

Whenever I try to walk to Kellogg he gets hostile without me even talking to him. is it Nick or something else? I tried telling Nick to wait outside and I even dismissed him. Please help.

Comment: @fja3omega The only way equipped power armour turns people hostile is if you have the Targeting Mod installed in the helmet. The Targeting Mod applies a debuff in the game engine to the NPC in order to get the highlight. For NPCs that are programmed as "wary" of you (not immediately hostile but anything done to them will immediately set them off) just the act of being debuffed by the HUD can set them off.

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because if Kellogg doesn't die, you can't finish the game. *

> (1) equipped power armor,
>
> (2) companion is hostile,
>
> (3) weapons is not holstered,
>
> (4) bug or glitch happening while you walk to him.

(5) There's probably a script that keeps checking if he isn't hostile, to make him hostile, to facilitate progression.

---

(*) *Guy Beats Fallout 4 Without [they themselves personally] Killing Anyone, Nearly Breaks The Game* – [kotaku.com](https://kotaku.com/guy-beats-fallout-4-without-killing-anyone-nearly-brea-1749882569) (the hard part was Kellogg, because he *must* die)

Comment: In my first play through I blew the director's head off with a shot gun, 3 seconds after I finally had my agency back and could draw a weapon. *That* I had to reload from. With this, all you're missing is some dialogue options with a jerk.

Comment: *Nearly Breaks The Game* - lol - as if that's an achievement in a Bethesda game, as opposed to a prerequisite...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I did the quest I just walke in with my power armor and gun holstered. I had Preston graves as my companion. When I talked to him though, eventually he has to become hostile because of what you’re saying. Try to pick a different companion or holster your gun.